# POST "/v1/rest-apis" create forests on the given group

Tags: marklogic

Current architecture:
In the cluster there are two groups, `e-node` and `d-node`.

1. `e-node` : `e-host`
2. `d-node` : `d-host1` and `d-host2`

I am trying to do a POST call to `d-host1:8002/v1/rest-apis` with below configuration.

```
{
    "rest-api": {
        "name": "node-http-server",
        "group": "e-node",
        "database": "content",
        "modules-database": "rest-modules",
        "port": "9600",
        "forests-per-host": 1,
        "error-format": "json"
    }
}
```

output of the above request is that it's creating total 2 forests on both the d-node hosts (1-1 on d-host1 and d-host2) and 1 http server on e-host.

Is it possible to configure in a way to create forests on `e-node` hosts in the above JSON request?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to create the forests on the d-node group? Typically we refer to d-nodes as the data nodes that have forests and e-nodes as the evaluator nodes that are responsible for accepting connections and hosting the application servers.

Comment: Yes right,creating  only the modules database on the e-node, all other content dbs are on d-node.